# Display image byte type from database into DataGridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Good Morning. I am Learning C# and I got a problem. I have my datagridView with some rows and columns. So, I want to display to my datagridView image but, when do it, in the column "Imagem", show me "matriz byte[]", instead of my image.

The type of my "imagem" in my database is "Varbinary(MAX)". So, have something like 0Xffd8ff0001............ in my database.

My code to load my data into datagridView is below. the name of my DatagridView is "tabelAplicFerr":

```
private void AplicadoresFerramentasControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Login.conectData);
            con.Open();
            DataSet dsFerramentas = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter daFerramentas = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Ferramenta_ID,Imagem, Nome_Afinação, Vedante, Data_Criação, Observações, Utilizador FROM Ferramentas " +
                "JOIN FormasCravação ON FormasCravação.Cravação_ID = Ferramentas.Cravação_ID " +
                "JOIN TipoAfinação ON TipoAfinação.Afinação_ID = Ferramentas.Afinação_ID", con);

            dsFerramentas.Clear();
            daFerramentas.Fill(dsFerramentas, "Ferramentas");
            tabelAplicFerr.DataSource = dsFerramentas;
            tabelAplicFerr.DataMember = "Ferramentas";

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

In my  "SqlDataAdapter daFerramentas", I have in select "imagem". I get matrix byte[]", instead of my image.

How can I solve this problem?

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and SQL server 2008.

Hope you can help me. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You have to convert the byte array imagem to an image to dispaly it to the end user

Comment: How can I do it @lyz?

Comment: @mjwills i aready put my grid looks.

Comment: This video show how to fill a datagridview with images https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3Toz0qiDwk 
this person reads the images from file, in your case you can create image from byte array using Imge.FromStream method
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
{
    return Image.FromStream(ms);
}
@Bráulio Joelson

Comment: @lyz that's the problem of all videos that I saw. this works, if the path of the image is local but they don't show in case to get from database and convert byteArray to a Image. I will save your link for something as the video case.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

I went to my datagridView design, and I simply put a column with Type imageColumn. follow the printscreen to see more details.

Click to add new column and after that I choose DatagrideViewImageColum. In my datagridView now show the image.

[image]